# Powershell setting COM+ Enforce access checks for this application

Tags: powershell, com+

I'm having problems figuring out what is the Powershell string for choosing the "Enforce access checks for this application" under the Security tab of the properties for that application.  Here is what I have so far for Powershell in choosing other things:

```
$comAdmin = New-Object -comobject COMAdmin.COMAdminCatalog
$apps = $comAdmin.GetCollection("Applications")
$apps.Populate();
$app = $apps | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq $targetApp}

$app.Value("Identity") = $identity
$app.Value("Password") = $passwordEncrypted
$app.Value("ApplicationDirectory") = $appRootDir
$app.Value("ConcurrentApps") = 1 # set to default
$app.Value("RecycleCallLimit") = 0 # set to default
$app.Value("Activation") = 1 # dedicate local server process
$apps.SaveChanges()
```

Now I have all those other strings for the value but I can't figure out the one for the "Enforce access checks for this application"?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be

```
$app.Value("ApplicationAccessChecksEnabled") = 0
```

I'm not positive because when I set the above value it doesn't change in the COM+ properties.  I'm not sure if there is something wrong with setting that field.  I also tried changing the value through the property gui and using the following to get the current value:

```
$app.Value("ApplicationAccessChecksEnabled")
```

Thanks